# lmtp: connect(backend) failed: Connection refused

Tags: linux, smtp, authentication, email-server, imap

A long time ago I'm trying to fix this error but I'm still locked, I appreciate any help :).

I detail all that I have and what I am trying to do.

I am using Cyrus Murder and apparently everything works fine until It try to delivery the mail to backend using lmtp.

I have:

- **1 frontend** ( name = frontendlinux.ejemplo.org , ip = 169.254.220.13 )
- **1 backend**  ( name = backend.ejemplo.org , ip = 169.254.220.14 )

I tried the DNS with nslookup and works well.

In both servers operating system is: *Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 i686 GNU/Linux.*

I show the configuration files and then the log files.

**/etc/cyrus.conf (frontendlinux)**

```
START {
        recover         cmd="/usr/sbin/ctl_cyrusdb -r"
        idled           cmd="idled"
        delprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/cyr_expire -E 3"
        tlsprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/tls_prune"
}

SERVICES {
        sieve           cmd="timsieved" listen="sieve" prefork=0 maxchild=100
        mupdate         cmd="mupdate -m -T 1800" listen=3905 prefork=1 maxfds=1024000 maxforkrate=20 proto=tcp4 maxfds=256 -U 5 -T 10
        imap            cmd="proxyd" listen="imap" prefork=1 maxchild=100 maxforkrate=2 proto=tcp4 maxfds=256 -U 5 -T 10
        lmtp            cmd="lmtpproxyd" listen="lmtp" prefork=1 maxchild=20 maxforkrate=2 proto=tcp4 maxfds=256  -U 5 -T 10
        lmtpunix        cmd="lmtpproxyd" listen="/var/run/cyrus/socket/lmtp" prefork=1 maxchild=20 maxforkrate=2 maxfds=256  -U 5 -T 10

        listen="/indicesimap/var/run/cyrus/socket/lmtp" prefork=1
        notify         cmd="notifyd" listen="/var/run/cyrus/socket/notify" proto="udp" prefork=1
}

EVENTS {
        checkpoint      cmd="/usr/sbin/ctl_cyrusdb -c" period=5
        delprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/cyr_expire -E 3" at=0401
        tlsprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/tls_prune" at=0401
        delprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/cyr_expire -X 14" at=0200
        delprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/cyr_expire -D 14" at=0400

}
```

**/etc/imapd.conf (frontendlinux)**

```
configdirectory: /var/lib/cyrus
partition-default: /var/spool/cyrus/mail
allowusermoves: yes
altnamespace: no
unixhierarchysep: yes
lmtp_downcase_rcpt: yes
lmtp_over_quota_perm_failure: 0
admins: cyrus techforce-admin cyrmaster cyrlmtp mupdateuser
lmtp_admins: mupdateuser postman cyrlmtp
mupdate_admins: mupdateman mupdateuser
imap_admins: cyrus mupdateuser techforce-admin
proxy_authname: mupdateuser
proxy_password: senha
allowanonymouslogin: no
popminpoll: 1
autocreatequota: 0
umask: 077
sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail
sieveusehomedir: false
sievedir: /var/spool/sieve
hashimapspool: true
allowplaintext: yes
sasl_mech_list: PLAIN
sasl_minimum_layer: 0
virtdomains: userid
defaultdomain: ejemplo.org
sasl_pwcheck_method: saslauthd auxprop
sasl_auxprop_plugin: sasldb
sasl_auto_transition: no
tls_ca_path: /etc/postfix/sslcerts/
tls_session_timeout: 1440
tls_cipher_list: TLSv1+HIGH:!aNULL:@STRENGTH
mupdate_server: frontendlinux
mupdate_username: mupdateuser
mupdate_authname: mupdateuser
mupdate_password: senha
lmtpsocket: /var/run/cyrus/socket/lmtp
idlemethod: idled
idlesocket: /var/run/cyrus/socket/idle 
syslog_prefix: cyrus
statuscache_db: skiplist
userdeny_db: skiplist
skiplist_always_checkpoint: 1
singleinstancestore: 1
proxyd_disable_mailbox_referrals: 1
sieve_allowreferrals: 0
proxyd_allow_status_referral: 0
serverlist: backend
backend_authname: mupdateuser
backend_password: senha
backend_mechs: PLAIN
mupdate_config: standard
partition-news: /var/spool/cyrus/news 
newsspool: /var/spool/news
```

**/etc/postfix/lmtp_passwd (frontendlinux)**

```
169.254.220.13 mupdateuser:senha
```

And run the command: su - postfix -c "/usr/sbin/postmap /etc/postfix/lmtp_passwd"

**/etc/postfix/main.cf (frontendlinux)**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/sslcerts/linuxdrops.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/sslcerts/linuxdrops.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = frontendlinux
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localdomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost, ejemplo.org
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 169.254.220.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 20000000
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname
inet_protocols = ipv4
relay_domains = $myorigin
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_relay_domains
mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:169.254.220.13:lmtp
local_recipient_maps =
lmtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
lmtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/lmtp_passwd
lmtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
lmtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
lmtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf (frontendlinux)**

```
smtp      inet n        -       -       -       -        smtpd -v
pickup    fifo n        -       -       60      1        pickup
cleanup   unix n        -       -       -       0        cleanup
qmgr      fifo n        -       n       300     1        qmgr
tlsmgr    unix -        -       -       1000?   1        tlsmgr
rewrite   unix -        -       -       -       -        trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix -        -       -       -       0        bounce
defer     unix -        -       -       -       0        bounce
trace     unix -        -       -       -       0        bounce
verify    unix -        -       -       -       1        verify
flush     unix n        -       -       1000?   0        flush
proxymap unix -         -       n       -       -        proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1        proxymap
smtp      unix -        -       -       -       -        smtp
relay     unix -        -       -       -       -        smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
showq     unix n        -       -       -       -        showq
error     unix -        -       -       -       -        error
retry     unix -        -       -       -       -        error
discard   unix -        -       -       -       -        discard
local     unix -        n       n       -       -        local
virtual   unix -        n       n       -       -        virtual
#lmtp      unix -        -       -       -       -        lmtp -v
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp -v
anvil     unix -        -       -       -       1        anvil
scache    unix -        -       -       -       1        scache

maildrop unix -         n       n       -       -        pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

uucp      unix -        n       n       -       -        pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

ifmail    unix -        n       n       -       -        pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix -        n       n       -       -        pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix -        n       n       -        2        pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix -        n       n       -       -        pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

**/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf (frontendlinux)**

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
saslauthd_path: /var/run/saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
log_level: 7
```

**/etc/cyrus.conf (backend)**

```
START {
        recover         cmd="/usr/sbin/ctl_cyrusdb -r"
        mupdatepush   cmd="/usr/sbin/ctl_mboxlist "
        delprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/cyr_expire -E 3"
        tlsprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/tls_prune"
}

SERVICES {
        imap            cmd="imapd -U 30" listen="imap" prefork=1 maxchild=100 maxforkrate=20 proto=tcp4 maxfds=256 -U 5 -T 10
        lmtp            cmd="lmtpd" listen="backend:lmtp" prefork=1 maxchild=20 babysit=true maxforkrate=2 proto=tcp4 maxfds=256 -U 5 -T 10
        sieve           cmd="timsieved" listen="sieve" prefork=0 maxchild=100
        notify          cmd="notifyd" listen="/var/run/cyrus/socket/notify" proto="udp" prefork=1
}

EVENTS {
        checkpoint      cmd="/usr/sbin/ctl_cyrusdb -c" period=5
        delprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/cyr_expire -E 3" at=0401
        tlsprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/tls_prune" at=0401
        delprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/cyr_expire -X 14" at=0200
        delprune        cmd="/usr/sbin/cyr_expire -D 14" at=0400

}
```

**/etc/imapd.conf (backend)**

```
configdirectory: /var/lib/cyrus
defaultpartition: default
partition-default: /var/spool/cyrus/mail
allowusermoves: yes
allowallsubscribe: 1
duplicatesuppression: 1
expunge_mode: delayed
partition-news: /var/spool/cyrus/news
newsspool: /var/spool/news
altnamespace: no
unixhierarchysep: yes
lmtp_downcase_rcpt: yes
lmtp_over_quota_perm_failure: 0
admins: cyrus techforce-admin cyrmaster mupdateuser
lmtp_admins: mupdateuser postman
mupdate_admins: mupdateman mupdateuser
imap_admins: cyrus mupdateuser  techforce-admin
proxyservers: mupdateuser cyrus
proxy_authname: mupdateuser
proxy_password: senha
allowanonymouslogin: no
popminpoll: 1
autocreatequota: 0
umask: 077
sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail
sieveusehomedir: false
sievedir: /var/spool/sieve
hashimapspool: true
allowplaintext: yes
sasl_mech_list: PLAIN
sasl_minimum_layer: 0
loginrealms: localhost ejemplo.org backend.ejemplo.org frontendlinux.ejemplo.org backend frontendlinux
virtdomains: userid
defaultdomain: ejemplo.org
sasl_pwcheck_method: alwaystrue
sasl_auxprop_plugin: sasldb
sasl_auto_transition: no
tls_ca_path: /etc/postfix/sslcerts/
tls_session_timeout: 1440
tls_cipher_list: TLSv1+HIGH:!aNULL:@STRENGTH
mupdate_server: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org
mupdate_username: mupdateuser
mupdate_authname: mupdateuser
mupdate_password: senha
lmtpsocket: /var/run/cyrus/socket/lmtp
idlesocket: /var/run/cyrus/socket/idle
notifysocket: /var/run/cyrus/socket/notify
syslog_prefix: cyrus
statuscache_db: skiplist
userdeny_db: skiplist
skiplist_always_checkpoint: 1
singleinstancestore: 1
serverlist:  backend
backend_authname: mupdateuser
backend_password: senha
backend_mechs: PLAIN
proxyd_disable_mailbox_referrals: 1
sieve_allowreferrals: 0
proxyd_allow_status_referral: 0
```

Log in frontendlinux

```
    postfix/lmtp[3756]: deliver_request_get: file active/706B36086B
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: deliver_message: from user1@ejemplo.org
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_parse_destination: 169.254.220.13:lmtp 24
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: connecting to 169.254.220.13 port 24
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_addr_one: host 169.254.220.13
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: begin 169.254.220.13 address list
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: pref    0 host 169.254.220.13/169.254.220.13
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: end 169.254.220.13 address list
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_connect_addr: trying: 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13] port 24...
  cyrus/lmtp[3647]: telling master 2
  cyrus/lmtp[3647]: accepted connection
  cyrus/lmtp[3647]: telling master 3
  cyrus/master[3461]: service lmtp pid 3647 in READY state: now unavailable and in BUSY state
  cyrus/master[3461]: service lmtp now has 0 ready workers
  cyrus/master[3461]: service lmtp pid 3647 in BUSY state: now serving connection
  cyrus/master[3461]: service lmtp now has 0 ready workers
  cyrus/lmtp[3647]: connection from .ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13]
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: vstream_tweak_tcp: TCP_MAXSEG 16384
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: global TLS level: none
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 220  Cyrus LMTP Murder v2.4.16-Debian-2.4.16-4+deb7u1 server ready
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: > 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: LHLO 
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 250-
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 250-8BITMIME
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 250-PIPELINING
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 250-SIZE
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 250-AUTH PLAIN
  cyrus/master[3757]: set maximum file descriptors to 256/256
  cyrus/mupdate[3520]: New worker thread started, for a total of 3
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 250 IGNOREQUOTA
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: match_string: PLAIN ~? plain
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: server features: 0x102f size 0
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: Using LMTP PIPELINING, TCP send buffer size is 170840, PIPELINING buffer size is 4096
  cyrus/master[3757]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus/bin/lmtpproxyd
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: maps_find: smtp_sasl_passwd: hash:/etc/postfix/lmtp_passwd(0,lock|fold_fix): 169.254.220.13 = mupdateuser:senha
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_sasl_passwd_lookup: host `169.254.220.13' user `mupdateuser' pass `senha'
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: starting new SASL client
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: name_mask: noanonymous
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_sasl_authenticate: 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: SASL mechanisms PLAIN
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: xsasl_cyrus_client_get_user: mupdateuser
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: xsasl_cyrus_client_get_passwd: senha
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: xsasl_cyrus_client_first: uncoded initial reply: \0mupdateuser\0senha
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: > 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: AUTH PLAIN AG11cGRhdGV1c2VyAHNlbmhh
  cyrus/lmtp[3647]: login: .ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13] mupdateuser PLAIN User logged in
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 235 Authenticated!
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: > 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: MAIL FROM:<user1@ejemplo.org> SIZE=526
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: > 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: RCPT TO:<user1@ejemplo.org>
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: > 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: DATA
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
  cyrus/mupdate[3520]: cmd_find(fd:18, user.user1)
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 250 2.1.0 ok
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 250 2.1.5 ok
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=120 enable_deadline=0
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 354 go ahead
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=180 enable_deadline=0
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: > 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: .
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: > 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: QUIT
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=600 enable_deadline=0
  cyrus/mupdate[3520]: cmd_find(fd:18, user.user1)
  cyrus/lmtp[3647]: USAGE user1 user: 0.004000 sys: 0.004000
  cyrus/lmtp[3647]: connect(backend) failed: Connection refused
  cyrus/lmtp[3647]: telling master 1
  cyrus/master[3461]: service lmtp pid 3647 in BUSY state: now available and in READY state
  cyrus/master[3461]: service lmtp now has 2 ready workers
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: < 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13]:24: 451 4.4.3 Remote server unavailable
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: connect to subsystem private/defer
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr nrequest = 0
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr flags = 0
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr queue_id = 706B36086B
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr original_recipient = user1@ejemplo.org
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr recipient = user1@ejemplo.org
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr offset = 4294967295
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr dsn_orig_rcpt = rfc822;user1@ejemplo.org
  cyrus/lmtp[3757]: executed
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr notify_flags = 0
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr status = 4.4.3
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr diag_type = smtp
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr diag_text = 451 4.4.3 Remote server unavailable
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr mta_type = dns
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr mta_mname = 169.254.220.13
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr action = delayed
  postfix/lmtp[3756]: send attr reason = host 169.254.220.13[169.254.220.13] said: 451 4.4.3 Remote server unavailable (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

Comment: Dumping this mountain on us and then expecting us to sift through it for you is really unreasonable. Please take a few minutes to sort through it yourself and narrow things down a little. I can't speak for anyone else, but there's no way I'm going to feel charitable enough dig through this much raw data.

Comment: Sorry, try to get as complete as possible so that they see best it can be. Now remove the log information.
thanks

Comment: Include (keep) the *relevant* information (especially *error messages*), and make it easy for us to find that information. More information is usually better than less, but remember most of us are doing this on downtime at work -- If something is going to take an hour to analyze it it's less likely to get our attention.

Comment: Now I could solve.
I tell them if anyone happens the same error.
**Replace**: lmtp            cmd="lmtpd" listen="backend:lmtp" prefork=1 maxchild=20 babysit=true maxforkrate=2 proto=tcp4 maxfds=256 -U 5 -T 10
**by**:lmtp            cmd="lmtpproxyd" listen="lmtp" prefork=1 maxchild=20 maxforkrate=2 proto=tcp4 maxfds=256  -U 5 -T 10

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Convert [OP comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/540577/lmtp-connectbackend-failed-connection-refused#comment622667_540577) to CW</sub>

Now I could solve. I tell them if anyone happens the same error.

In `/etc/cyrus.conf` replace this line

```
lmtp cmd="lmtpd" listen="backend:lmtp" prefork=1 maxchild=20 babysit=true maxforkrate=2 proto=tcp4 maxfds=256 -U 5 -T 10
```

with

```
lmtp cmd="lmtpproxyd" listen="lmtp" prefork=1 maxchild=20 maxforkrate=2 proto=tcp4 maxfds=256 -U 5 -T 10
```